# How to make Fossil track file and folder renames?

Tags: version-control, file-rename, fossil

I'm experimenting with Fossil SCM, and while it is a great piece of software overall, there are a couple of real roadblocks for me. The major one is the renames: it seems that Fossil can't track file/folder name changes without hand-holding, that is I need to run `fossil mv` for each file/folder being renamed **and** rename the files/folders on the filesystem myself.

I've seen [this thread](https://fossil-users.fossil-scm.narkive.com/n1Tgycqu/how-to-move-rename-a-file-or-directory), but it is 15 years old. Maybe there have been improvements in this area since then? Does anyone know how to automate this?

PS
There are a couple of other questions regarding Fossil, I will post them separately, since packing several questions in one post is not welcome here.

Comment: I think you'll get faster answers, from the people who know Fossil best, on the dedicated [Fossil forum](https://fossil-scm.org/forum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, Fossil can apply renames on the filesystem as well as in its repository, using the [mv-rm-files](https://fossil-scm.org/home/help?cmd=mv-rm-files) setting:

> If enabled, the `mv` and `rename` commands will also move the associated files within the check-out -AND- the `rm` and `delete` commands will also remove the associated files from within the check-out.

You can also explicitly use the `--hard` option when using the [rename](https://fossil-scm.org/home/help?cmd=rename) command.

See also this forum post: https://fossil-scm.org/forum/forumpost/ecc3f14f7215028a41fee6d1a94d2ea894cb5cf19b0caf4b544020a5601d04da.